# Events availability from the container to the child element

Tags: javascript

In the following code, I have a DIV parent container which has a SPAN container and the SPAN container containing the INPUT child elements.

When I click the gray area which is for the DIV, I see the 'I'm clicked!' message. I also see the same message when I click the white area of the SPAN or the input elements.

Shouldn't the SPAN container prevent the DIV container **onclick** event?

```
<div onclick="clicked()" style="padding: 20px; background-color: gray">
    <span style="padding: 10px; background-color: white">
        <label for="us">US</label>
        <input type="radio" name="us" />
        <label for="canada">Canada</label>
        <input type="radio" name="canada" />
        <label for="europe">Europe</label>
        <input type="radio" name="europe" />
    </span>
</div>

<script>
    function clicked() {
        alert("I'm clicked!");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It's correct. It's called bubbling. Click event bubbled up the DOM tree. So when you click on child the event next propagates to its parent, and so on until html root.

Comment: So, the 'click' event is bubbled from the child element to any immediate parent which can handle the 'click' event. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
<div id="clickableDiv" style="padding: 20px; background-color: gray">
    <span id='spanEle' style="padding: 10px; background-color: white">
        <label class="input-area" for="us">US</label>
        <input class="input-area" type="radio" name="us" />
        <label class="input-area" for="canada">Canada</label>
        <input class="input-area" type="radio" name="canada" />
        <label class="input-area" for="europe">Europe</label>
        <input class="input-area"`enter code here` type="radio" name="europe" />
    </span>
</div>


<script>
    $(document),ready(function(){
      $("#clickableDiv").bind('click', function(e){
          if(e.target.id != 'spanEle' && !$('#'+e.target.id).hasClass('input-area')){
            alert("I am clicked!");
          }
      });
    });
</script>
```